# Laravel large cron tasks don't work properly

Tags: php, laravel, cron

I have a task in laravel that every hour checks if there is any txt file to process in a folder, if it finds any file it opens it and reads each line to start a series of steps which includes connecting to web services and saving movements in database.

The problem is that when it is a small data it works perfectly, but with somewhat large data (more than 1100 records) the command that runs this task always throws me this error:

[image]

So I must modify the task so that it skips the lines that I already process and continue with the ones that have not yet been read and so on until the task manages to finish reading the file each time it is executed.

What should I configure so that this does not happen?

I just wrote this on file Kernel.php:

```
$schedule->command('imp:kenan')->hourly()
```

Hope you guys can help me.

Greetings and thanks in advance.

Comment: If your cron is taking more then default `max_execution_time` to finish the task, then try by increasing it in the cron. `@ini_set('max_execution_time, 0); set_time_limit(0);`

Comment: @Haridarshan Thanks for reply, well i set my max execution time in my php.ini  to 3 hours and it fails after 1 and half hour, so i dont know why it doesnt take that time, anyways let me try adding the set_time_limit at the task beggining.

Comment: Both are same so If you've already increased `max_execution_time` then no need to use `set_time_limit(0);`. Have you tried increasing `memory_limit` as well?

Comment: @Haridarshan I modified the php.ini and its the same result, even this time it took less than usual to fail T_T

Answer (score 0):

I have a very similar issue with my setup. Best solution I could find is to move to Larwvel Queue system. Maybe create some jobs for each update and speed up the process.

Another somaybe increase the execution time for php.